# Logstash + MongoDB Atlas OUTPUT : Failed to handshake with xxx.gcp.mongodb.net:27017: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)

Tags: mongodb, logstash, mongodb-atlas

Trying to output data from Logstash to MongoDB Atlas (cluster running on GCP).

Done :

- Whitelisted all IPs (0.0.0.0/0)

My logstash config :

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 28777
    codec => json
   }
}

output {
   mongodb {
    uri => "mongodb+srv://xxx:xxx@xxx.gcp.mongodb.net/collect?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true"
    database => "collect"
    collection => "requests"
    generateId => true
   }
  stdout {
    codec => json
  }
}
```

I also tried with this URI :

```
uri => "mongodb+srv://xxx:xxx@xxx.gcp.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true"
```

But i'm getting :

```
[2020-09-19T16:01:22,253][WARN ][logstash.outputs.mongodb ][main] MONGODB | Failed to handshake with xxx.gcp.mongodb.net:27017: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
[2020-09-19T16:01:22,253][WARN ][logstash.outputs.mongodb ][main] MONGODB | Failed to handshake with xxx.gcp.mongodb.net:27017: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
[2020-09-19T16:01:22,253][WARN ][logstash.outputs.mongodb ][main] MONGODB | Failed to handshake with xxx.gcp.mongodb.net:27017: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
[2020-09-19T16:01:22,255][WARN ][logstash.outputs.mongodb ][main] MONGODB | Error running ismaster on xxx.gcp.mongodb.net:27017: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
[2020-09-19T16:01:22,255][WARN ][logstash.outputs.mongodb ][main] MONGODB | Error running ismaster on xxx.gcp.mongodb.net:27017: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
[2020-09-19T16:01:22,255][WARN ][logstash.outputs.mongodb ][main] MONGODB | Error running ismaster on xxx.gcp.mongodb.net:27017: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

Update: this happens even if I'm not sending any data.

Comment: You need to get the complete stack trace to troubleshoot that. Put a breakpoint on the line that logs "Error running ismaster" and get the current stack trace from there.

Comment: Any way to do that ? currently I just have a docker image with the mongodb plugin loaded and a conf file...

Comment: You can try adding mcve instructions to the question.

Comment: That's already the case but thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe for someone who already has logstash running.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open issue in the latest version of the plugin.
https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-mongodb/issues/60

However, plugin version 3.1.5 seems to be working. install it with this command and restart logstash:
`/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install --version=3.1.5 logstash-output-mongodb`